# Bluetooth mouse lags after 5 seconds of idling

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, bluetooth, mouse

I have Logitech Master MX 3 that I am connecting over Bluetooth.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29). (output of lspci)

The driver in use is iwlwifi.

The mouse stutters after not being moved for 5 seconds.

However, I have an observation that, when the Blueman - Bluetooth devices applet is open, the lag disappears! As soon as I close that application, it starts again.

I have tried many things like:

1. btusb.enable_autosuspend=0 in the grub file.
2. iwlwifi/iwlmvm power management switched off, power scheme 0

are just to list a few.

Kernel version:5.13.0-27-generic x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux (uname -romi)
iwlwifi Driver version: 46.4d093a30.0 (lshw -C Network)

Answer (score 4):

- Install powertop `sudo apt install powertop`.
- Run it with `sudo powertop`.
- Press Tab until you reach Tunables.
- Search for all the "Autosuspend for USB device..." options.
- Change them from "Good" to "Bad" with Enter key.

Comment: signed up just to vote for this comment. that lag was really annoying, thank you so much